# How can I create an accordion with jQuery in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to create an accordion that is a little bit different than most.

**What I am trying to do:**

- Have a *title* that when clicked a *description* is displayed across the width of the page
- I would like to have the titles split across the screen into three columns; therefore the title would not span the width of the page

Basically looking for something like this:

[image: No items clicked]
[image: Once the first item is clicked]
[image: If the second item is clicked]

As you can see this is a little different then most cases.  I found a live demo of something similar to what I am trying to do, this can be found [here](http://www.swankcapital.com/who-we-are/our-team/business-development.aspx).

**What I've done so far:**

I have been using the Cherry Framework and using shortcodes to try to get this to work, but I run into issues when I try to expand the description out from the title.  Not sure if there is a way to edit the *accordian* shortcode to allow the description to go the full width or not, but I think that would be ideal.

Here is my code thus far:

```
    [tabs direction="top" tab1="the first tab" tab2="the second tab" tab3="the third tab"]
[tab1]

[row]

[span4]

[accordion title="Title 1"] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras lorem lectus, porta et nulla ut, bibendum placerat sem. Aliquam a consequat ante, cursus posuere eros. Fusce ac turpis in turpis elementum malesuada vitae eu urna. Curabitur felis enim, luctus vitae pharetra eget, aliquam quis sem. Mauris ipsum erat, sodales et aliquet in, vehicula ut nisl. Aliquam vestibulum diam dictum odio mollis, ut pretium erat elementum. Nunc ornare, quam vitae maximus tincidunt, elit nunc ornare neque, ut tincidunt lorem orci at sem. Sed arcu tellus, vulputate non ante vitae, varius congue urna. Duis sed lacus est. Mauris eu lacus ac enim fermentum vestibulum. Pellentesque pellentesque ornare auctor. Curabitur imperdiet ipsum et justo bibendum, eget eleifend dui iaculis. 

[/accordion]

[/span4]

[span4]

[accordion title="Title 2"] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras lorem lectus, porta et nulla ut, bibendum placerat sem. Aliquam a consequat ante, cursus posuere eros. Fusce ac turpis in turpis elementum malesuada vitae eu urna. Curabitur felis enim, luctus vitae pharetra eget, aliquam quis sem. Mauris ipsum erat, sodales et aliquet in, vehicula ut nisl. Aliquam vestibulum diam dictum odio mollis, ut pretium erat elementum. Nunc ornare, quam vitae maximus tincidunt, elit nunc ornare neque, ut tincidunt lorem orci at sem. Sed arcu tellus, vulputate non ante vitae, varius congue urna. Duis sed lacus est. Mauris eu lacus ac enim fermentum vestibulum. Pellentesque pellentesque ornare auctor. Curabitur imperdiet ipsum et justo bibendum, eget eleifend dui iaculis. 

[/accordion]
[/span4]

[span4]

[accordion title="Title 3"] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras lorem lectus, porta et nulla ut, bibendum placerat sem. Aliquam a consequat ante, cursus posuere eros. Fusce ac turpis in turpis elementum malesuada vitae eu urna. Curabitur felis enim, luctus vitae pharetra eget, aliquam quis sem. Mauris ipsum erat, sodales et aliquet in, vehicula ut nisl. Aliquam vestibulum diam dictum odio mollis, ut pretium erat elementum. Nunc ornare, quam vitae maximus tincidunt, elit nunc ornare neque, ut tincidunt lorem orci at sem. Sed arcu tellus, vulputate non ante vitae, varius congue urna. Duis sed lacus est. Mauris eu lacus ac enim fermentum vestibulum. Pellentesque pellentesque ornare auctor. Curabitur imperdiet ipsum et justo bibendum, eget eleifend dui iaculis. 

[/accordion]
[/span4]

[/row]

[row]

[span4]

[accordion title="Title 4"] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras lorem lectus, porta et nulla ut, bibendum placerat sem. Aliquam a consequat ante, cursus posuere eros. Fusce ac turpis in turpis elementum malesuada vitae eu urna. Curabitur felis enim, luctus vitae pharetra eget, aliquam quis sem. Mauris ipsum erat, sodales et aliquet in, vehicula ut nisl. Aliquam vestibulum diam dictum odio mollis, ut pretium erat elementum. Nunc ornare, quam vitae maximus tincidunt, elit nunc ornare neque, ut tincidunt lorem orci at sem. Sed arcu tellus, vulputate non ante vitae, varius congue urna. Duis sed lacus est. Mauris eu lacus ac enim fermentum vestibulum. Pellentesque pellentesque ornare auctor. Curabitur imperdiet ipsum et justo bibendum, eget eleifend dui iaculis. 

[/accordion]
[/span4]

[span4]

[accordion title="Title 5"] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras lorem lectus, porta et nulla ut, bibendum placerat sem. Aliquam a consequat ante, cursus posuere eros. Fusce ac turpis in turpis elementum malesuada vitae eu urna. Curabitur felis enim, luctus vitae pharetra eget, aliquam quis sem. Mauris ipsum erat, sodales et aliquet in, vehicula ut nisl. Aliquam vestibulum diam dictum odio mollis, ut pretium erat elementum. Nunc ornare, quam vitae maximus tincidunt, elit nunc ornare neque, ut tincidunt lorem orci at sem. Sed arcu tellus, vulputate non ante vitae, varius congue urna. Duis sed lacus est. Mauris eu lacus ac enim fermentum vestibulum. Pellentesque pellentesque ornare auctor. Curabitur imperdiet ipsum et justo bibendum, eget eleifend dui iaculis. 

[/accordion]
[/span4]

[span4]

[accordion title="Title 6"] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras lorem lectus, porta et nulla ut, bibendum placerat sem. Aliquam a consequat ante, cursus posuere eros. Fusce ac turpis in turpis elementum malesuada vitae eu urna. Curabitur felis enim, luctus vitae pharetra eget, aliquam quis sem. Mauris ipsum erat, sodales et aliquet in, vehicula ut nisl. Aliquam vestibulum diam dictum odio mollis, ut pretium erat elementum. Nunc ornare, quam vitae maximus tincidunt, elit nunc ornare neque, ut tincidunt lorem orci at sem. Sed arcu tellus, vulputate non ante vitae, varius congue urna. Duis sed lacus est. Mauris eu lacus ac enim fermentum vestibulum. Pellentesque pellentesque ornare auctor. Curabitur imperdiet ipsum et justo bibendum, eget eleifend dui iaculis. 

[/accordion]
[/span4]
[/row]
```

Here are the screenshots for what I have:
[image: Nothing clicked]
[image: Clicked first item]
[image: Clicked next 2 items]

Like I said I am using shortcodes to do this as of right now.  I am sure there is an easier way to do this where I would not run into issues where the description text does not go across the width of the page.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Below is an example please check the code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.main ul li').click(function(){
      $('.main ul li').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
      $('.main ul li').css('margin-bottom','1%');
      $('.innerBox').hide();
      var boxHeight=$(this).children('.innerBox').innerHeight();
      $(this).css('margin-bottom', boxHeight);
      $(this).children('.innerBox').slideDown();
      var widthUL = $('.main ul').width() - 10;
      var test = $(this);
      var leftUL = test.position().left;
      $('.innerBox').css({'width': widthUL,'margin-left':- leftUL});      
    });
  });
```

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.clrfix:after{
  content:'';
  clear:both;
  display:block;
}
.main{
  width:900px;
  margin:0 auto;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.main ul li{
  padding:.5%;
  width:31%;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  list-style:none;
  margin:1%;
  display:inline-flex;
  position: relative;
  border-radius:5px;
}
.main ul li.active{
  background:#d7e3de;
  border:1px solid #333;
  border-bottom:none;
  padding:1%;
  border-radius:0;
}
.main ul li.active .innerBox{
  top:37px;
}
.main ul li .innerBox{
  background:#d7e3de;
  position:absolute;
  left:-1px;
  display:none;
  top:38px;
  z-index:1;
  border:1px solid #333;
  padding:10px;
  min-height:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
    <ul class="clrfix">
      <li>Title here
        <div class="innerBox">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</div>  
      </li>
      <li>Title here
        <div class="innerBox">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</div>  
      </li>
      <li>Title here
        <div class="innerBox">test</div>  
      </li>
      <li>Title here
        <div class="innerBox">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</div>  
      </li>
      <li>Title here
        <div class="innerBox">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</div>  
      </li>
      <li>Title here
        <div class="innerBox">test</div>  
      </li>
      <li>Title here
        <div class="innerBox">test</div>  
      </li>
      <li>Title here
        <div class="innerBox">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat caborum</div>  
      </li>
      <li>Title here
        <div class="innerBox">test</div>  
      </li>
      <li>Title here
        <div class="innerBox">test</div>  
      </li><li>Title here
        <div class="innerBox">test</div>  
      </li>

      <li>Title here
        <div class="innerBox">test</div>  
      </li>
      <li>Title here
        <div class="innerBox">test</div>  
      </li><li>Title here
        <div class="innerBox">test</div>  
      </li>
      <li>Title here
        <div class="innerBox">test</div>  
      </li>
      <li>Title here
        <div class="innerBox">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</div>  
      </li>

      <li>Title here
        <div class="innerBox">test</div>  
      </li><li>Title here
        <div class="innerBox">test</div>  
      </li>
      <li>Title here
        <div class="innerBox">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco labint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</div>  
      </li>
      <li>Title here
        <div class="innerBox">test</div>  
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
```

And I hope I'll helps you

Comment: I was able to add <script> </script> and <style> </style> to both the javascript and css portions.  I am still having issues getting the javascript to actually work though.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @theNoobGuy I'm not getting you properly what you want to say. Can you please elaborate.

Comment: @theNoobGuy you will probably have to wrap Maddys code in a function in order to get the $ to work properly: (function($) { //code here })( jQuery ); I suggest testing the code on [JS.Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) first instead of trying to drop it directly into your WP site.

Comment: @Maddy, I was able to get this to work for the most part!  The only issue now is when I am on my mobile device, things do not show up properly.  Is there a way to change this for mobile?

Comment: @Maddy, I also noticed that on the first click on one of the titles there is a bunch of white space that pops up below the description.  Thoughts on this?

Answer (score 2):

what if you make the description th same with as the title so it will come up just not 100% but the same width as the title. I don't know how wordpress works but in simple html and css this might work.

if this doesn't work make you can try to make them columns in css

for example this will make 2 columns with a blue solid line of 1px in between them.

```
  -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-count:2 ; /* Firefox */
  -webkit-column-width: 50%; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-width: 50%; /* Firefox */
  -webkit-column-rule-style: solid; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-rule-style: solid; /* Firefox */
  -webkit-column-rule-width: 1px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-rule-width: 1px; /* Firefox */
  -webkit-column-rule-color: blue; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-rule-color: blue; /* Firefox */
```

this is not really css but it will work in Firefox, Chrome, Safari and opera IE wont work but I have found [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh673534%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which does the same as far as I know.